# How react native scroll text?

Tags: react-native

How react native scroll text?

I have a long text in a fixed height container. I want to show a part of text in that container and scroll it when I want to see more.

I have try overflow scroll but react native seems not support overflow scroll.

Thanks.

Comment: Scroll view works perfectly in react-native. please add something if you have tried and that didn't work.

Comment: can you be more specific. have you seen [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) Component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use ScrollView for this case. Just put your text inside it and set height to scroll view.

Answer (score 6):

I'm used the following code. Take `ScrollView` and put your any element inside `ScrollView`.

```
render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>

       <ScrollView>       

         <Text>
           Add your text
         </Text>      

       </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a limitation in React Native where you can't set `height` directly on the `ScrollView` `style` prop. So, I suggest you do the following if you also want to set the height:

```jsx
<View style={{ height: 100 }}>
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>
      Your text goes here.
    </Text>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Or alternatively using `flexGrow`:

```jsx
<ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0.2 }}>
  <Text>
    Your text goes here.
  </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Relevant issue I found: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3422

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{ height: hp(3)}}>
 <ScrollView>
     <Text style={{ fontSize: hp(2) }}>
         Your text goes here
     </Text>
 </ScrollView>
```